# Is it possible to create a short URL that redirects to a longer URL if that short URL currently doesn't exist?

Tags: redirects, url

I've a URL that's very long. I need to put the URL into a hardcopy format but it looks ridiculous on paper. The URL performs well so changing it is not on the cards.

Would it be possible to write a redirect from a non existent URL to this one?

`www.example.com/salespage` (the non-existing url) would redirect to the longer URL of `www.example.com/firstdirectory/seconddirectoy/my-very-long-salespage`

The above would mean someone can type or click on `www.example.com/salespage` which then opens up the longer URL of `www.example.com/firstdirectory/seconddirectoy/my-very-long-salespage`

Comment: I assume by "doesn't exist" you mean that the short URL currently returns a "404 Not Found" status?

Comment: Well there is no current short url so yes, it would be a 404 until I create it - however would it work if I didn't create the short url?

Comment: This is just a standard "redirect". You "create the URL" by creating the redirect. If the URL did "already exist" (ie. it returned content) then creating the redirect would probably override this (although that depends on how you implement the redirect). However, exactly _how_ you create the redirect is dependent on your system. Are you using Apache, IIS or Nginx or something else? Are you using a CMS (WordPress, Drupal, Joomla, etc.) with a redirection plugin?

Comment: I'll be using a htaccess 301 redirect as it's a plain html site.